# C# Generics: How can I use them generically?

Tags: c#, generics

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMyGenericBaseClasses()
{ 
    Type typeCrazy = ThisPartyIsTypeCrazyWOOT();

    // How do I create a generic object?
    MadnessOhYeah<typeCrazy> sanity = new MadnessOhYeah<typeCrazy>();

    // How do I use a generic object after it has been created?
    Assert.IsTrue(sanity.MyTrueFunction(), "this is sparta");

    // How do I call a generic function generically?
    bool result = MyFunction<typeCrazy>();

    Assert.IsTrue(result, "I did not get my teeth whitened!");

}
```

Is there any way to make this compile? (ThisPartyIsTypeCrazyWOOT returns a Type)  Because this is a test, we're not concerned about having to use reflection or anything, unless that's just absolutely crazy.

I'm getting the vibe that this isn't going to be possible though, and that our test functions will just have to be more specific.

Comment: What is the compile error? I suspect you will need to add a contraint to the MadnessOhYeak class that the generic type is a 'newable'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 2**: The first example I posted still doesn't 100% answer the question, since it involves a cast to `List<int>`, which is a type that is known at compile time. Below is a reflection-only solution that illustrates how you *can* use a generic type knowing nothing about the type argument itself. But, as you can see, it's... well, disgusting ;)

```
Type userType = GetUserSuppliedType();

// Now let's say userType is T.
// Then here we are getting the type typeof(List<T>).
// But, of course, there's no way to have any such information in the code.
Type listOfUserType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(new[] { userType });

// This is effectively calling new List<T>();
object listObject = Activator.CreateInstance(listOfUserType);

// Do you see how messy this is getting?
MethodInfo addMethod = listOfUserType.GetMethod("Add");

// We better hope this matches userType!
object input = GetUserSuppliedInput();

// I suppose we could check it, to be sure...
if (input == null || input.GetType() != userType)
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException("That isn't going to work!");
}

// Here we are finally calling List<T>.Add(input) -- just in the most ass-
// backwards way imaginable.
addMethod.Invoke(listObject, new[] { input });
```

---

**Update**: OK, if you *insist* on doing this, here's an example of how it's *possible*—but very cumbersome!

```
Type genericListType = typeof(List<>);
Type listOfInt32Type = genericListType.MakeGenericType(new[] { typeof(int) });

object listObject = Activator.CreateInstance(listOfInt32Type);

List<int> list = (List<int>)listObject;

list.Add(1);
```

---

Generics can't quite work like this because a `Type` object could be anything. Consider this code:

```
var list = new List<int>();
list.Add(1);
```

The type of `list` in the above code is known to be `List<int>`, which defines what operations are legal on `list` such as `Add(1)`.

Now consider this instead:

```
Type t = GetTypeFromIndeterminateSourceSuchAsUserInput();
var list = new List<t>();
list.Add(?);
```

When `t` is a `Type` object rather than the *name* of a type (like `int`) which the compiler can parse, it's not really possible to instantiate a generic type using that type—or rather, it's *possible* (see [Andrey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513165/c-generics-how-can-i-use-them-generically/4513179#4513179)), but you can't really *use* the resulting object in any sort of generic way.

Now, you might think that something like this ought to work:

```
Type t = typeof(int);
var list = new List<t>();
list.Add(1);
```

...but just because the value of `t` is known (by you) at compile time doesn't change the way things work in general.

Anyway, yes it's possible using reflection; but if you go down that path, you're committing to a pretty reflection-heavy solution. What I'm getting at is that in general it isn't a particularly realistic thing to do.

Comment: Do you have any examples of ways doing this with reflection?  I modified my question to make it better.

Comment: @thepaulpage: I've added an example. As you can see, it's really not pretty; but maybe it can help you somehow.

Comment: Well... I see what you're doing there, but we really need to use the object that we create (while still being ignorant of the type). While your example doesn't do that, it does as much as it can.  I guess this means that the answer is "no".

Comment: @thepaulpage: I posted a second example illustrating how, technically, you really *can* use a generic type in code while remaining *completely* oblivious of its type arguments. But, as you will hopefully agree, the approach is pretty appalling. Anyway, I'll let you judge for yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the full example.  You're correct that it is horrible, but since it's only a test method, we might look into it anyway.  I'm trying to do what we need in a T4 at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

You need [Type.MakeGenericType Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype.aspx). Then [Activator.CreateInstance Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx).

Comment: I can't see how I would use the object after it's created with this method.